# Jssor Slider set duration for all images

Tags: jssor

I can't seem to find how to set a duration time for the slides, the original timing is to slow for me.

I read that I have to use $Idle, but I don't know where and how

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

```
var jssor_1_options = {
    $Idle: 2000  //in milliseconds
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but where exactly do I have to put it? In what file I mean...